# Rename files in a folder based on names in a different folder

Tags: python, text-files, rename

I have 2 folders, each with the same number of files.  I want to rename the files in folder 2 based on the names of the files in folder 1.  So in folder 1there might be three files titled:

Landsat_1,
Landsat_2,
Landsat_3

and in folder 2 these files are called:

1,
2,
3

and I want to rename them based on folder 1 names.  I thought about turning the item names of each folder into a a .txt file and then turning the .txt file in a list and then renaming but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.  Any suggestions?

Edit:

I have simplified the file names above, so just appending with Landsat_ wil not work for me.

The real file names in folder 1 are more like LT503002011_band1, LT5040300201_band1, LT50402312_band4.  In folder 2 they are extract1, extract2, extract3.  There are 500 files in total and in folder 2 it is just a running count of extract and a number for each file.

Comment: Make sure your script is from the parent directory.

Comment: Then sort each list and `zip` them together in order to rename.

Comment: You should probably show a more real example of filenames, unless your real filenames are also just a prefix to a number.

Comment: Oh, so you just want to match them by sort order? E.g. 'extract1' is renamed 'LT503002011_band1', 'extract2' is renamed to 'LT5040300201_band1', etc?

Comment: Yep thats exaclty what I want to do!

Comment: How do you want to sort the LT*_band* files? Lexicographically gives `['LT503002011_band1', 'LT50402312_band4', 'LT5040300201_band1']`. Or if you want to sort by the value of the numbers, it would be `['LT50402312_band4', 'LT503002011_band1', 'LT5040300201_band1']`. Or something else?

Comment: They will be sorted numerically so smallest numbers will be first and largest last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone said, "sort each list and zip them together in order to rename".

Notes:

- the `key()` function extracts all of the numbers so that `sorted()` can sort the lists numerically based on the embedded numbers.
- we sort both lists: `os.listdir()` returns files in arbitrary order.
- The `for` loop is a common way to use zip: `for itemA, itemB in zip(listA, listB):`
- `os.path.join()` provides portability: no worries about `/` or `\`
- A typical invocation on Windows: `python doit.py c:\data\lt c:\data\extract`, assuming those are directories you have described.
- A typical invocation on *nix: : `python doit.py ./lt ./extract`

```
import sys
import re
import os

assert len(sys.argv) == 3, "Usage: %s LT-dir extract-dir"%sys.argv[0]
_, ltdir, exdir = sys.argv

def key(x):
    return [int(y) for y in re.findall('\d+', x)]
ltfiles = sorted(os.listdir(ltdir), key=key)
exfiles = sorted(os.listdir(exdir), key=key)

for exfile,ltfile in zip(exfiles, ltfiles):
    os.rename(os.path.join(exdir,exfile), os.path.join(exdir,ltfile))
```

Comment: I am new to using python as a way to access the os, I mainly use it for csv file manipulation so please forgive what is probably a simple quesiton.  Is `ltdir` equivalent to the pathway for my folder 1 and `exdir` equivalent to the pathway for my folder 2?

Comment: Yes, the variables `ltdir` and `exdir` take on whatever values are passed in on the command line. In this case, I expect that you would enter the respective directory paths that you have described above.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the glob package which takes a filename pattern and outputs it into a list. For example, in that directory

```
glob.glob('*')
```

gives you

```
['Landsat_1', 'Landsat_2', 'Landsat_3']
```

Then you can loop over the filenames in the list and change the filenames accordingly:

```
import glob
import os

folderlist = glob.glob('*')
for folder in folderlist:
    filelist = glob.glob(folder + '*')
    for fil in filelist:
         os.rename(fil, folder + fil)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: is the asterisk in the glob.glob command the pathway to the filenames?  Is the second asterisk what I want to change the file name to?

Comment: The asterisk is just saying which files/folders should be selected. "asterisk" indicates all of the files in the current directory while "Landsat_2/asterisk" indicates all of the files in Landsat_2. (Sorry for some reason asterisks don't show up in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I went for more completeness :D.

```
# WARNING: BACKUP your data before running this code. I've checked to
# see that it mostly works, but I would want to test this very well
# against my actual data before I trusted it with that data! Especially
# if you're going to be modifying anything in the directories while this
# is running. Also, make sure you understand what this code is expecting
# to find in each directory.

import os
import re


main_dir_demo = 'main_dir_path'
extract_dir_demo = 'extract_dir_path'


def generate_paths(directory, filenames, target_names):
    for filename, target_name in zip(filenames, target_names):
        yield (os.path.join(directory, filename),
               os.path.join(directory, target_name))


def sync_filenames(main_dir, main_regex, other_dir, other_regex, key=None):
    main_files = [f for f in os.listdir(main_dir) if main_regex.match(f)]
    other_files = [f for f in os.listdir(other_dir) if other_regex.match(f)]

    # Do not proceed if there aren't the same number of things in each
    # directory; better safe than sorry.
    assert len(main_files) == len(other_files)

    main_files.sort(key=key)
    other_files.sort(key=key)

    path_pairs = generate_paths(other_dir, other_files, main_files)
    for other_path, target_path in path_pairs:
        os.rename(other_path, target_path)


def demo_key(item):
    """Sort by the numbers in a string ONLY; not the letters."""
    return [int(y) for y in re.findall('\d+', item)]


def main(main_dir, extract_dir, key=None):
    main_regex = re.compile('LT\d+_band\d')
    other_regex = re.compile('extract\d+')

    sync_filenames(main_dir, main_regex, extract_dir, other_regex, key=key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(main_dir_demo, extract_dir_demo, key=demo_key)
```

Comment: I will give this a try, thanks for your help!  I am definitely using copies of the dataset before running on my real data thanks for looking out though.